# Question on Campaigns API (Create an Ad Template)

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Banno provides campaign management APIs. Details are here in this docs - https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/ads/management/

But we need description and sample values for the "Request body" parameters in Campaigns API

Below is the example request body given in the docs for "Ad template" creation.

```
{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "templateType": "banking",
  "forInstitutionId": "string",
  "fields": [
    {}
  ],
  "html": "string",
  "published": true,
  "defaultWidth": 0
}
```

**Our Questions**

a) What is "fields" array. Give a description for this array and example values that we could pass in this array
b) What is "html" field. Give a description and also some examples for this field.

Answer (score 0):

`fields` will be an array of **Blocks**. We are working on updating our docs to provide the defined Block types that you can use.

I will update this answer when the documentation updates are published.

Comment: Hi Sam, Any update on the documentation

Comment: Hi Sam, Any updates on the documentation

Comment: None to report yet